# Significato di "arrivare alle croste" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, idioms, regional

Nel racconto *Il paese*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Come rientrarono, c’era qualcosa in aria nel retro, e precisamente la vecchia Jeanne che se la prendeva con suo marito, di un tono tra il flebile e lo sdegnato. – Ti sei alzato alle otto, io alle quattro. Mi hai fatto colazione per due, a pranzo hai mangiato per quattro ed hai preteso la torta di zucchini, sapendo lo straordinario lavoro che mi dà. Tra stamattina e adesso hai fumato venti sigarette minime, hai bevuto due birre e quattro gazose, hai sgranocchiato un etto di caramelle, e adesso mi rivuoi della birra. Se non ti **arrivavo alle croste**, già l’avevi grattata.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione  "arrivare alle croste" che appare in questo passaggio. Ho cercato alla voce "crosta" in alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovata. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire?

Comment: Da quel che intendo, "grattata" si riferisce alla birra, e quindi potrebbe probabilmente significare "te la saresti già presa (di soppiatto); "grattare" si usa come sinonimo di "rubare". La moglie rimprovera il marito di mangiare a ufo.
L'espressione "arrivare alle croste" secondo me si riferisce alla crosta del formaggio (visto che si parla di cibo), e  significa "sono arrivata tardi (dopo aver mangiato tutto il commestibile stavi a intaccare pure la crosta del formaggio) ma appena in tempo per fermarti dallo scolarti l'ennesima birra"

Comment: Arrivare alle croste significa arrivare alle spalle, sorprendere alle spalle. In questo caso se non l'avesse sorpreso avrebbe già rubato (grattato, nel testo) nuovamente la birra.

Comment: @abarisone da dove arriva questo modo di dire? Sono curioso! :)

Comment: In Liguria e in basso Piemonte, quando si dice _avere sulle croste_ qualcuno significa avere qualcuno a carico (in senso figurato le croste sono le spalle). In senso spregiativo _stare sulle croste_ significa avere qualcuno che sta sulle scatole, che infastidisce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Arrivare alle croste*** significa arrivare alle spalle, sorprendere alle spalle. In questo caso se non l'avesse sorpreso avrebbe già rubato (grattato, nel testo) nuovamente la birra.

In Liguria e in basso Piemonte, quando si dice *avere sulle croste* qualcuno significa avere qualcuno a carico (in senso figurato le croste sono le spalle). In senso spregiativo *stare sulle croste* significa avere qualcuno che sta sulle scatole, che infastidisce.