# Cosa significa "dare nomi" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Il paese*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Paco rise, e il messo scosse la testa. Arrivò la voce del marito, le **dava nomi**, ma d’un tono sordo, affogato dallo stesso eccesso di mantenimento.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "dare nomi" in questo testo? L'ho cercata alla voce "nome" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non l'ho trovata, perlomeno non  scritta esattamente così, con "nomi" in plurale. Unicamente nel [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/nome) ho trovato

> **dare nome** 
>   loc.v. 
>   CO 
>   chiamare, nominare

ma non credo che questo sia il significato nel brano.

Comment: Potrebbe significare che la insultava, la apostrofava con epiteti offensivi. Appena riesco a capire il contesto potrò essere più preciso.

Comment: @abarisone: Il contesto è quello della mia domanda precedente: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9945/significato-di-arrivare-alle-croste-in-questo-contesto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dare nomi, nel contesto da te citato, vuol significare che il marito la insultava, la apostrofava con epiteti (cioè nomi) offensivi.

Il tono era sordo affogato dallo stesso eccesso di mantenimento, cioè il marito non voleva manifestare apertamente l'astio verso la moglie e cercava di salvaguardare le apparenze.

Comment: A orecchio, suona anche a me così, ma riusciamo a trovare una fonte?

Comment: Quindi "mantenimento", che era un vocabolo che neanche capivo, farebbe riferimento al fatto che il marito cercava di non esprimere i suoi sentimenti verso la moglie?

Comment: Più che altro significa che il marito da una parte insultava la moglie mentre dall'altra non voleva dare troppa enfasi agli insulti o pronunciarli in maniera sguaiata per non sembrare eccessivo. Per quanto riguarda il vocabolo [mantentimento su Treccani - Sinonimi e Contrari](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mantenimento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/), l'accezione che mi sembra più calzante in questo contesto è nella 1. cioè salvaguardia.